# How to count number of rows in other tables using mysql inner join?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 following tables:

**crm_customers:**

[image]

**crm_progress:**

[image]

**crm_notifications:**

[image]

I want following result:

[image]

To achieve above required output, I'm using following query:

```
SELECT `cc`.`customer_id`, `cc`.`customer_name`, COUNT(`cp`.`progress_customer`) AS Progress, COUNT(`cn`.`notification_customer`) AS Notifications 
FROM `crm_customers` AS `cc` INNER JOIN `crm_progress` AS `cp` 
ON `cc`.`customer_id` = `cp`.`progress_customer` 
INNER JOIN `crm_notifications` AS `cn` 
ON `cn`.`notification_customer` = `cp`.`progress_customer` 
WHERE `cc`.`customer_id` = 1 AND `cc`.`customer_status` = 1
```

But the result comes out to be totally wrong. However, when I join only 2 tables then the result is accurate.

The following query brings correct output:

```
SELECT `cc`.`customer_id`, `cc`.`customer_name`, COUNT(`cp`.`progress_customer`) AS Progress 
FROM `crm_customers` AS `cc` INNER JOIN `crm_progress` AS `cp` 
ON `cc`.`customer_id` = `cp`.`progress_customer` 
WHERE `cc`.`customer_id` = 1 AND `cc`.`customer_status` = 1
```

Where am I doing wrong? How to use join correctly to fetch required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query: you need to count progress_id and notification_id which are associated with certain customer

```
SELECT `cc`.`customer_id`, `cc`.`customer_name`, COUNT(distinct `cp`.`progress_id`) AS Progress, COUNT(distinct `cn`.`notification_id`) AS Notifications 
FROM `crm_customers` AS `cc` INNER JOIN `crm_progress` AS `cp` 
ON `cc`.`customer_id` = `cp`.`progress_customer` 
INNER JOIN `crm_notifications` AS `cn` 
ON `cn`.`notification_customer` = `cp`.`progress_customer` 
WHERE `cc`.`customer_id` = 1 AND `cc`.`customer_status` = 1 
group by `cc`.`customer_id`, `cc`.`customer_name`
```

Comment: your solution is way simpler than that of @Prasad Wargad. But I'm wondering whether `GROUP BY` is really needed in this query or not?

Comment: when you will use aggregation like count, max, min, avg that time you need to use group by as you are selecting other coulmn also along with aggregated columns.

Comment: ok that's alright I already knew but query works pretty fine even without using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved using below query:

```
SELECT `cc`.`customer_id`, `cc`.`customer_name`, COUNT(*) AS Progress, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Notifications 
FROM `crm_customers` AS `cc` 
INNER JOIN `crm_notifications` AS `cn` ON `cc`.`customer_id` = `cn`.`notification_customer` 
WHERE `cc`.`customer_id` = 1 AND `cc`.`customer_status` = 1 
GROUP BY `cc`.`customer_id`) AS Notifications 
FROM `crm_customers` AS `cc` 
INNER JOIN `crm_progress` AS `cp` ON `cc`.`customer_id` = `cp`.`progress_customer` 
WHERE `cc`.`customer_id` = 1 AND `cc`.`customer_status` = 1 
GROUP BY `cc`.`customer_id`
```